# Laravel - change specific tr bgcolor in views using controller based on parameter

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to change the color of my table rows based on my parameter. here's my code:

**AdminController.php**

```
public function table_row(){

    if ($walk->is_paid && $walk->is_completed) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-success';
    }
    elseif (empty($walk->is_paid) && $walk->is_completed) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-warning';
    }
    elseif ($walk->is_cancelled) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-danger';
    }
    return view('walks', compact('$highlightClass'));
}
```

**walks.blade.php**

```
<tr class="{{ $highlightClass }}">
```

It didn't work.. :(

Here's the image of table in my views:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOzEX.jpg)

Comment: Did you add `css`?

Comment: Is it going to `else` condition which is not there?

Comment: I didn't code any css for this one, I only use bootstrap class. @Priya : none.

Comment: try to simply print {{ $highlightClass }} in blade and see whats output there?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the way to send data to views. Remove the `$` in compact method.

```
public function table_row(){
    $highlightClass = "";

    if ($walk->is_paid && $walk->is_completed) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-success';
    }
    elseif (empty($walk->is_paid) && $walk->is_completed) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-warning';
    }
    elseif ($walk->is_cancelled) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-danger';
    }

    return view('walks', compact('highlightClass')); // not $highlightClass
}
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_compact.asp

```
// walks.blade.php

<tr class="{{$highlightClass or ''}}">
```

Comment: I have an error occur: Undefined variable: highlightClass (View: C:\wamp64\www\zenporto-web\app\views\walks.blade.php)

Comment: Yeah sometime it will go to else condition. that should be verified using an empty initialisation. `$highlightClass = '';` at Ln:2

Comment: else{
        return view('walks');
        } just added else but same error occured.

Comment: You can do that as well. But two return statement, not suggested as in view you are using `$highlightClass` and you have only one template.

Comment: Could you please try the way now the solution has been given and tell if any error is occurring ? In view you are using $highlightClass and you have only one template which will search for the variable. and you are returning `walks` template without required data. `return view('walks');` wont work.

Comment: you can do `return view('walks');` only if template is `<tr class="{{$highlightClass or ''}}"> `

Comment: Yes I would like to return the data with none as it was stated in "else". As I added it in my walks.blade.php  the code or ''  -> <tr class="{{$highlightClass or ''}}"> . The bug was dissapeared but the bgcolor in row didn't take effect in my table.

Comment: Can we move this convo in skype? so that I could share screen my work for more clearer view on what's happening in my problem. :(

Comment: Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes
Your class names are wrong may be thats why its not showing. Remove `bg-` from classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass with function:

```
public function table_row(){
    $highlightClass = "";

    if ($walk->is_paid && $walk->is_completed) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-success';
    }
    elseif (empty($walk->is_paid) && $walk->is_completed) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-warning';
    }
    elseif ($walk->is_cancelled) {
        $highlightClass = 'bg-danger';
    }

   return View::make('walks')
                        ->with('highlightClass', $highlightClass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove $ from compact and try**

return view('walks', compact('highlightClass'));

and learn how compact work actually in laravel :- [*https://www.quora.com/What-does-compact-do-in-Laravel*][1]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a standard to send the data to view file. Create an array and add all the data (that you want to send to view file) in that array with key and fetch data with their key on view file.

```
public function table_row(){
  $data = array();
  $data['highlightClass'] = "";
  if ($walk->is_paid && $walk->is_completed) {
    $data['highlightClass'] = 'bg-success';
  }
  elseif (empty($walk->is_paid) && $walk->is_completed) {
    $data['highlightClass'] = 'bg-warning';
  }
  elseif ($walk->is_cancelled) {
    $data['highlightClass'] = 'bg-danger';
  }
  return view('walks',$data); 
}
```